# Drupal Calendar, why some events appear as "all day" events even if they are not "all day" events?

Tags: views, datetime

Why some events appear as "all day" events even if they are not "all day" events in Calendar Views?

[image]

As you can see, these events have just a start date defined at 00:00. But they are not "all day" events:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an old "bug" in calendar: https://drupal.org/node/881224
Have you tried to give your dates an end date?

Comment: Hmm.. The problem is that this website is already in production, and I can no more change the field settings to allow an end date. For this project I have setup two different fields for start date & end date. May be I can change something directly in the module code, but I cannot figure out what.